# How to capture an image using CameraX and send it directly to server in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-camera

I currently learning Android and try to clone WhatsApp. I use Jetpack Compose here and also use CameraX. I already have a CameraX being setup but I confused to get the image bitmap, and How do I can a implement photo capture and send it to server?(set as avatar or send friend a pic). I red the docs but still get confused about how image being uploaded to server works.